# Saving array and objects within said array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to make a simple to do app using vue.js, I want to try and save my to-dos that are set in the array so that when I reset the site, they still remain. Looking through some of the documentation I arrived at this:

```
data() {
        return {
            array: [
                 {id: 1, label: 'learn vuejs'},
            ]
        }
    }, 
methods: {
        persist() {
            localStorage.array = this.array;
            alert('items saved')
        }
    },
mounted() {
        if (localStorage.array && localStorage.array.id) {
            this.array = localStorage.array;
            this.array[id] = localStorage.array.id;
        }
    },
```

while this does save my array to localStorage,  IT DOES NOT THE OBJECTS WITHIN. When I check localStorage in the console it shows :

> array: "[object Object]"

anyone knows how to save the items within the array? if you do please explain it to me.

Comment: If you print your saved object into the console the default `toString` method will be used. That won't work on nested objects. Try `JSON.stringify(obj)`

Comment: Also, you won't be able to access you'r array with `localStorage.array.id`. As "array" is no object, there won't be an `id` property.
Only `localStorage.array[0].id` would work as you have to tell javascript which index (object in this case) of your array you want to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store them as string. So `localStorage.array = JSON.stringify(this.array)`, and when fetching from localStorage `this.array = JSON.parse(localStorage.array);`

Comment: @Danesinhell that's how json is stored. You need to `JSON.parse()` it to get js readable object.

Comment: thank you so much, it was a mistake in my code that messed with the loading